# camel rest servlet 404 instead of 405

Tags: servlets, post, apache-camel

Using the sample code from Camel in github in [1](https://github.com/smparekh/camel-example-servlet-rest-tomcat) I am getting 404 instead of 405.

This is a summary of the code in [1](https://github.com/smparekh/camel-example-servlet-rest-tomcat)

```
rest("/provider").description("Provider rest service").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json").get("/{id}").description("Find provider by id").outType(Provider.class).to("bean:providerService?method=getProvider(${header.id})");
```

When I send this I am getting the right answer.
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/providerservice/rest/provider/123

When I send this I am getting 404. I am expecting 405
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/providerservice/rest/provider/123

I appreciate any help!!

Comment: Source Code is at https://github.com/smparekh/camel-example-servlet-rest-tomcat/blob/master/src/main/java/com/redhat/examples/rest/RestRouteBuilder.java

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was you whom logged a JIRA ticket about this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12050

But this functionality has now been implemented and will be in the upcoming Apache Camel 2.21.0 release onwards.